# how do I access c:\program files\windowsapps in windows 8 after I set its properties

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, file-access

I am running a vb.net application that I created. It is running in Windows 8 and the application needs to start a process. Apparently the process needs access to the c:\program files\windowsapps folder. So following the instructions I found on this site, I was able to change the owner of the folder to my ID that I use to log in and run my program with. When I run my application I still get the access denied message to that folder. When I look at File Explorer, I can now see all of the files and folders in that directory. But I can no longer get to the properties of the folder to change the settings.

How do I change the settings of that folder once I have access to it and why is my program still not able to access the folder? Is my program running as a different user? and if so, which one?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by admin privileges? I am now the owner of the folder. My logged in ID is in the Local Admin group. I can't get back to the place where I change the securities setting of the WindowsApps folder.

Comment: If you are trying to do this interactively (File Explorer), you need to open the Program Files folder with elevated Admin privileges. Just being an admin on the machine does not automatically let everything run elevated.